# Shadowing a JMS queue without consuming with Spring

Tags: spring, jms, hornetq, spring-jms

I’m looking to write a little Spring JMS debugging utility that can shadow and log what is being posted onto a JMS queue (HornetQ on a remote server) but not consume the message as that is to be left to another MDB. Does the Spring allow this feature out of the box?

Comment: you want to log a message every time it's posted or you want to run a "tool" on an existing queue to see the content?

Comment: I am writing the 'tool' that can listen to a queue and get notification when a message appears and the tool will log it.

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that with a queue. You could a `QueueBrowser` but that's a synchronous operation.